# Changed access permissions of HOME folder in ubuntu.how to bring it back to the default permission

Tags: ubuntu

I changed the folder permission of my Home directory by mistake and it is throwing up the following message while system start up.

**User's $HOME/.dmrc is being ignored. THis prevents the default sesssion and language fron being saved File should be owned by user and have 644 permissions. User's $HOME directory must be owned by user and not writable by other users.**

The changes I did were,

sudo chown 777 weblab
And also changed the permissions by right clicking the home folder,weblab, and changing the permissions for ser,group and others to read and write.

Can some one help me in resolving this? Due to this I'm not able to access by phpmyadmin folder. It says Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!

**SOLUTION**

I rectified my problem which was actually a simple thing. But I had tried the round about way earlier. I just right clicked my home folder, selected the Properties tab, Permissions, ans changed the group and others as "Read Only". Now the problem is solved.. Silly of me not to try this earlier..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rectified my problem which was actually a simple thing. But I had tried the round about way earlier. I just right clicked my home folder, selected the Properties tab, Permissions, ans changed the group and others as "Read Only". Now the problem is solved.. Silly of me not to try this earlier..

Answer (score 1):

The home folder can normally be solved by running:

```
chmod 700 ~/
chmod 644 ~/.dmrc
```

from any terminal. The PHPMyAdmin thing is a little harder to solve, since I forget where ubuntu stores the stupid thing(And I don't think it's in the normal www folder).

If you know where it is you can solve that error by running:

```
chmod -R o-w /path/to/phpMyAdmin
```

And I should add that this doesn't belong on stack overflow, but probably one of the sister sites, probably server-fault given the linux/web server nature of your second question, but your main question probably belongs more strongly on super-user.

Comment: Yes, I had that doubt whether it could be posted in here. Sorry for posting in the wrong site, but I was in a hurry to solve the problem and StackOverflow responds very fast, that's why posted in here..

I think I solved the first problem, have to check by restarting the system.

I'm searching for the phpMyAdmin folder..

Comment: My phpmyadmin is in the public_html folder of my home folder. I did 
chmod -R o-w /home/weblab/public_html/phpmyadmin.
 Now the error message is:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/index.php on this server.

Comment: If I give chmod 700 ~/ and chmod 644 ~/.dmrc, I am not able to access anything.. I'm not able to work with my php application. So I changed it back to chmod 777 weblab. What is the problem? Help me plz